# Referencing different names in joins with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic association and sometimes I want to preload it's associations.
When I left join the model, my WHERE filters get lost because they don't referenced the named association.

```rb
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `companies` LEFT OUTER JOIN `key_values` `latest_information` ON `latest_information`.`attachment_id` = `companies`.`id` AND `latest_information`.`attachment_type` = 'Company' AND `key_values`.`name` = 'latest_information' WHERE `latest_information`.`id` IS NOT NULL
# => ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: symbol key_values.`name` not found
```

This is the query that is generated but it's invalid due to the key_values.name not being referenced.

Here's what my model looks like:

```rb
class Company < LeadRecord
  has_many :key_values, as: :attachment, dependent: :delete_all
  has_one :latest_information,
                        -> { KeyValue.latest('latest_information') },
                        class_name: KeyValue.to_s,
                        as: :attachment

end

class KeyValue < LeadRecord
  belongs_to :attachment, polymorphic: true

  def self.latest(name)
    order(created_at: :desc).where(name: name) # This is the source of the error
  end
end
```

I can probably fix this by passing addition parameters to `self.latest` such as the association name but I want to know if there's a better Rails way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the interim I have solved this by making this change on KeyValue.

```rb
# key_value.rb
  def self.latest(name, association_name = 'key_values')
    order(created_at: :desc).where("#{association_name}.name = ?", name)
  end

# company.rb
has_one association_name,
                        -> {
                          KeyValue.latest(
                            method_name.to_s,
                            association_name.to_s,
                          )
                        },
                        class_name: KeyValue.to_s,
                        as: :attachment
```